# how to traverse an ArrayList without using looping constructs?

Tags: java

In Java  how to traverse an ArrayList without using any looping constructs ?

Comment: if this is homework please tag it as such

Comment: its not a home work . One of my friend asked me this question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use recursion.

```
public void doSomethingToAll(List list)
{
    // Begin the recursion.
    doSomethingToAll(list, 0);
}

private void doSomethingToAll(List list, int index)
{
    // Break the recursion when we have processed the entire list.
    if (index >= list.size()) return;

    // Do whatever you want with the list.
    process(list.get(index));

    // Recursive step. Process the next element.
    doSomethingToAll(list, index + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not saying what I offer is the only and the best solution, but it's generic enough to be reused easily, type-safe, and allows you to break early in the course of your traversal.

You can easily extend it and make it generic to any type of collection.

---

### A Simple Traversal Implementation

The implementation is composed of:

- a reusable type-safe Actor class to define actions (if any),
- a reusable type-safe Traversal class,
- and an exception class used to break out early of a traversal.

By reusable I mean that once used on a collection you can reuse it without needing to reinstantiate it, so that you only need one instance per target behavior.

**Actor**

```
interface Actor<T> {

  void act(final T element) throws TraversalInterruptionException;
}
```

**Traversal**

```
class Traversal<T> {

  int      index = 0;
  Actor<T> actor = null;


  public Traversal(final Actor<T> a) {
    actor = a;
  }

  void traverse(final List<T> col) {
    if (index < col.size()) {
      final T element = col.get(index++);
      try {
        if (actor != null) {
          actor.act(element);
        }
        traverse(col);
      } catch (final TraversalInterruptionException e) {
        /* let's get out of there early */
        index = 0; // reset
      }
    } else {
      index = 0; // reset
    }
  }
}
```

**TraversalInterruptionException**

```
class TraversalInterruptionException extends Exception {
}
```

### Test It

```
  @Test
  public void test() {
    final List<String>      list          = new ArrayList<String>();
    final Traversal<String> strTraversal  = new Traversal<String>(new Actor<String>() {

      @Override
      public void act(final String element)
      throws TraversalInterruptionException {
        if ("exit".equals(element)) {
          throw new TraversalInterruptionException();
        }
        System.out.println(element);
      }
    });

    list.add("test1");
    list.add("test2");
    list.add("test3");
    list.add("exit");
    list.add("test4");

    strTraversal.traverse(list);
    strTraversal.traverse(list); // and again to test the reset
  }
```

### Output

```
test1
test2
test3
test1
test2
test3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something dumb like this:

```
void traverse(ArrayList list)
{
  traverseHelper(list, 0);
}

void traverseHelper(ArrayList list, int index)
{
  if (index == list.size())
    return;

  "visit" list.get(index);

  traverseHelper(list, index+1);
}
```

It uses recursion instead of iteration, but why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with recursion:

```
void traverse(ArrayList<Whatever> list, int cur)
{
   if (cur == list.size())
     return;
   else {
     Whatever elem = list.getAt(cur);
     System.out.println(elem);
     traverse(list, ++cur);
   }
}

void traverse(ArrayList<Whatever> list)
{
  traverse(list, 0);
}
```